# Math.floor not working for cartian test case

Tags: javascript, math, rounding, average, mean

I am doing a coding challenge that requires me to find the **rounded down** average of integer array elements. The challenge has 3 test cases, 2 of which pass, except for the last one which does not and i have no idea why. This is my code:

```js
function getAverage(marks){
  //TODO : calculate the downwar rounded average of the marks array
   return Math.floor(marks.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc + cur;
  })) / marks.length;
  
}
```

And these are the test cases:

```js
Test.assertEquals(getAverage([2,2,2,2]),2);
Test.assertEquals(getAverage([1,2,3,4,5,]),3);
Test.assertEquals(getAverage([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2]),1);
```

The last test case returns 1.125 instead of 1, even though I am rounding down the result. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Your parenthesizing is wrong. You are applying `Math.floor()` to the sum, instead of applying it to the quotient.

The first two test cases pass because the average is already an integer, so it doesn't matter whether you floor it or not.

Consider the difference between:

```
floor(1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2) / 8 = floor(9) / 8 = 9 / 8 = 1.125
```

and:

```
floor((1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2) / 8) = floor(9 / 8) = floor(1.125) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You only do your accumulation within the `floor`, not the division. You take the floor of a sum of integers, then divide that. The division should be moved inside the floor:

```
function getAverage(marks) {
  return Math.floor(marks.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    return acc + cur;
  }) / marks.length);
}
```